# animation is not cross-browser using "transform: rotate"

Tags: jquery, css

I'm doing an animation to rotate the element when you scroll, just get it to work in webkit but could not in other browsers:

jQuery

```
var $cog = $('#cog'),
    $body = $(document.body),
    bodyHeight = $body.height();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $cog.css({
        // this work
        'transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)',

        // this not work
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + ($body.scrollTop() / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kDSqB/1/)

Comment: Rotation with jQuery is a bit tricky... I would recommand using a little jQuery plugin such as [jQuery rotate](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the transform. If you try logging the scrollTop value you'll see that firefox always returns 0, that's because ff has the scroll attached to the html, not the body.
Here's a cross browser solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/kDSqB/9/

```
var $cog = $('#cog'),
    $body = $('body'),
    bodyHeight = $body.height();

function getScrollTop(){
    if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
        //most browsers except IE before #9
        return pageYOffset;
    }
    else{
        var B= document.body; //IE 'quirks'
        var D= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
        D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;
        return D.scrollTop;
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = getScrollTop();
    $cog.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + (scroll / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + (scroll / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + (scroll / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + (scroll / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform:rotate': 'rotate(' + (scroll / bodyHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

Comment: please note I optimized my answer a little bit. If you already copied it, consider redoing so.

Comment: you have forgotten the '-webkit-transform' for safari (mac)